# Eventlistener in JavaScript output

Tags: dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

This code display the textarea tag for console.log(abc) which is the ID, but for console.log(text) shows an error. Can anyone explain how value for console.log(abc) is getting executed and not for text class.
I haven't pass any argument to callback function. so how even for console.log(abc) it give an output. 
Thank you.

```js
    document.querySelector(".text").addEventListener("keydown", () => {
        console.log(abc);
        //console.log(event);
        console.log(text);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <textarea name="ab" class="text" id="abc" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code segment `document.querySelector("#abc")` gets the html element with an id of "abc".
The code segment:

```
.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
        console.log(abc);
})
```

is an event listener that listens for a keydown event and prints the html tag with the id of "abc"

Comment: So why this code doesn’t work if i pass Class instead of ID

Comment: The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document. So it show work if you pass a class like so `document.querySelector(".class-name")`